# FireDAC/Delphi 10.4.2 Connecting to Postgres server

Tags: postgresql, delphi, firedac

If I set all required properties of the TFDConnection component, I can connect to any of my Postgres servers without any problem.

I cannot not, however, hardcode the connection parameters in my application and i need to read them from an inifile at runtime, and thus set them at runtime as well.

I can see and set the 'Server' & 'Port' sub-properties of the FDConnection's params property at designtime without issues. However, when I try to set these 2 in code, the compiler complains about them not existing.

What might be goin on and, more importantly, how do I overcome this problem?
Thanks for any help!